# Python Selenium WebDriverWait Timeout Exception before code executes

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

EDIT: Issue resolved!

I'm having difficulties getting the innerHTML in order to access a tag because the program will timeout before I'm able to get the html back. I'm still relatively new, so the method I used was something that I found (and has worked once before in my code already).

Here's one of the websites I was trying to access: "https://blog.naver.com/lily8744/221229107142"

Here's the error message: "...*raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:*"

Here's the relevant section of code (my imports work because I've already used it in code above)

```
def pull_data(linksarray, textdata):

    for item in linksarray:
        driver.get(item)
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'body')))
        blog_post_inner = driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].innerHTML", wait)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(blog_post_inner, 'html.parser')

        for blogtext in soup.find_all('p', class_="se_textarea"):
            print(blogtext.get_text())
```

EDIT: I need the innerHTML because I need the tags, page source doesn't have the data I need.

Comment: Does all pages has element with `id="body"`?

Comment: all the pages in linksarray has an element with id="body". It's not the exact tag I need though, I actually need a tag <p class="se_textarea"> but I didn't know how to use WebDriverWait in that situation.

Comment: I resolved my problem!
Instead of using "presence_of_element_located", I used "frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it" and switched the 'mainFrame' which happens to have the html data that I needed.